# How to record 5 second snippets of audo using Twilio API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to continuously record 5 second snippets of audio from a phone call initiated using the Twilio API. I know that I can use TwiML and the `<Record>` verb, but the problem I am having is that sometimes my TwiML is in the middle of using the `<Say>` verb so I cannot update it with a new `<Record>` verb without interrupting `<Say>`.

I know that I can use the TwiML `<Record>` verb and once the max length of 5 seconds expires I can use the callback function to update the TwiML with a new `<Record>` and continue in this fashion. But I cannot interrupt the TwiML when I am using a `<Say>` in it and I need to be able to refresh `<Record>`.

Is there some way that I can setup a conference call such that I have one TwiML doing the `<Record>` and another sending the programmable voice with `<Say>`?

Comment: Why do you need 5 second snippets? Could you not record the entire conversation and then cut it into 5 second snippets on your server?

Comment: I essentially want to create a "semi-live" stream and pipe the result to the Watson Speech-To-Text API. From what I understand, Twilio does not allow you to access a live stream of the audio. The only way I could think to solve this problem was to take 5 second snippets of the stream and covert it as they come in.

Comment: I see what you're trying to get at, but I'm not sure you're going to be satisfied by this at all, breaking every 5 seconds is likely to break up speech and make it very hard for the speech recognition service to put it back together. I'd suggest asking for user inputs, using `<Record>` to receive them and then sending them off to the service.